# is it possible to list out all the applications that are installed in the iPhone device in a tableview with icon?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I want to collect the applications which are installed in the device and i want to list that with icons of applications.

Comment: It's a sandbox violation, you can't.

Comment: i want to list those apps..... no way for that?

Answer (score 1):

Apple's provacy concerns have always extended to an app querying what other apps are on the devices, but as of iOS 9 Apple have removed the ability to do so unless explicitly declared.

In the past a developer could use the method `- canOpenURL:` defined on `UIApplication` and passed in a URL known to be handled by another app to see if the user had that app on their phone. Whilst this would not be viable for getting a comprehensive list of the apps on a user's phone, it would serve to know if specific apps were there.

iOS 9 introduced the concept of whitelisting URL schemes, meaning that if you were going to query this you would have to explicitly state it in the .plist.

For a guide on how this works I recommend this article: http://www.dysonapps.com/blog/2015/9/13/developing-for-ios-9-canopenurl

The short answer is no, you cannot get a list of the other apps on a device.