# Get list of installed app name in iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I get my installed app names for my project. ?
Is it possible to access downloaded app in my newly created app ?
I want to create a app like app locking .

Comment: Apple does not provide an API for getting a list of installed apps, this has todo with privacy reasons. Your only option is to check app scheme of your apps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is it possible to list out all the applications that are installed in the iPhone device in a tableview with icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35668361/is-it-possible-to-list-out-all-the-applications-that-are-installed-in-the-iphone)

Comment: That's not possible with the public API, it's forbidden by the Apple development guidelines and that's a serious slur to user privacy. The most you can do is to check the presence of other of your apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access Other third-party apps or System Apps features or permissions via your app. There is no public API available to do so.

Comment: And in fact Apple does not want 3rd party apps to be able to do this. If you found a way around the limitation, Apple would remove your app from the app store and work to shut down your work-around in a future OS release.